# Make RecycleView show items in the middle of the screen, if the items are few

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I have programmed a simple linear RecycleView for my new alarm application. Since I am very new to Android programming I have run into such a question: now, all the items I have are shown from top to bottom, even if there are only, say 3 items at all. It doesn't look too good and not convenient also. Is there some way, if there are only few items in the list, to show them in the middle, rather than from top to bottom?

Thank you!!

My current main XML code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fadeScrollbars="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
        android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical|horizontal"
        tools:listitem="@layout/alarms_view" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the recycleView  `android:layout_height="match_parent"` to

```
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

then add these lines in your RecycleView.

```
app:layout_constraintCircleRadius="0dp"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can center all the recyclerView in the middle
for that change your recyclerView like the xml below

```
 <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:fadeScrollbars="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
        android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical|horizontal"
        tools:listitem="@layout/alarms_view" />
```

and when you add new item your recyclerview expand up to the height of screen

Comment: This one works also. But could you please explain, what exactly the width "0dp" does? 0dp means nothing, so doesn't it have some special meaning?

Comment: **official documentation** said that MATCH_PARENT is not recommended for widgets contained in a ConstraintLayout. Similar behavior can be defined by using MATCH_CONSTRAINT with the corresponding left/right or top/bottom constraints being set to "parent".https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout

Comment: Note that the MATCH_CONSTRAINT is 0dp

Comment: In my experience apart from the performance later when you use the constraintlayout and if you have a lot of the view you will find some layout problems when you use the match_parent

Answer (score 1):

Add layout gravity to parent layout and change `recyclerview` height to wrap content like this:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fadeScrollbars="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
        android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical|horizontal"
        tools:listitem="@layout/alarms_view" />
```